# Switching a 3v motor with a MOSFET using a 3.3v signal

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, dc-motor, 3.3v

****I have knowledge of programming but VERY little experience with electronics.****

I'm attempting to switch a MOSFET using a 3.3v signal from an Adafruit MCU module ([Adafruit Module here](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-feather-32u4-bluefruit-le?view=all)).  The load the MOSFET would be switching is a 3v water pump ([Water Pump Info here](https://www.micropumps.co.uk/TCSM200range.htm)).  The MOSFET that was chosen is the PMV28UNEA from Mouser.com ([MOSFET Datasheet here](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/916/PMV28UNEA-1320529.pdf)).

The problem I'm having is when the signal pin from the MCU is set to high, the MOSFET switches on but my multi-meter shows a voltage drop when the motor is connected.  Without the motor connected the voltage is around 4v (expected from the battery).  However, whenever I connect the motor, the voltage drops to around 2.30v and the motor will not cycle on.  The motor did cycle on once when I first tried it but hasn't since.  I can't figure out what's causing this drop in voltage. I've included a simple schematic along with the links to the MCU, pump, and MOSFET.  If I'm missing any relevant information here that would help please let me know.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbiTK3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Check your battery is properly charged

Comment: The battery is charged. It's fully depleted around 3.2v. The motor cycles on if I connect it directly to +3.7v and Gnd but I need it to switch on and off with the MCU.

Comment: How are you (physically) connecting all this? Since the motor needs a large current to start you might need to use soldered connections and somewhat thick wires for the path where that current flows. Also, give the MCU it own wire to the battery, I mean, don't make it share (part of) the wire the motor uses. This is because, when the motor is on current will flow and a voltage is dropped across those wires. That will then lower the supply to the MCU then the NMOS will get a lower Vgs and it might not fully switch on.

Comment: Are you sure your diode is connected at the right polarity on your circuit? The diode line should face the opposite to the mosfet

Comment: Right now every thing is plugged directly into a bread board except the MOSFET which is soldered to a PCB, due to it's SOT-23 package, then jumper wires are used to connect it to the breadboard. The batt is connected directly to the MCU via its built-on battery port. The MCU board has a BATT pin which allows for sourcing power directly from the battery. A wire leads directly from this pin to the (+) power line on the bread board. Gnd is connected the same way. Sorry for the non-detailed schematic, I was trying to keep it simple.

Comment: I'm reading a voltage of around 3v to the gate from the logic pin. The gate, from what I understand should be fully saturated around 1V.   Damien, this is how I've seen the shunting diode setup in other schematics, leading from Gnd to +V.

Comment: Did you monitor if the MCU is still alive? I you have the connections as shown in your schematic then one possibility is that when your battery is trying to power the motor from static it causes a voltage dip that caused your MCU to get reset

Comment: Yes the MCU is still alive. It's setup with a momentary button that is double tapped to turn the MOSFET on and held for about a sec to turn it off. There's also an accompanying audio tone from a piezo buzzer for each. The multimeter reads around 3v from the signal pin when it's set to high. Although, Bimpelrelkkie might be right given I think the output pin should be supplying 3.3v

Comment: What cables are you using to connect to your motors? if the cable size is too small it may not pass enough current to run the motor. Or the PCB trace for your MOSFET cannot allow sufficient current flow?

Comment: What you are labeling as an MCU is not an MCU but a complex circuit board.  You must not run the motor power through it, even if it seems to work (which in this case it does not).   Measure the voltage drops in all parts of the motor circuit and figure out where the voltage that is not seen across the motor is seen, for example, across the FET, or between pins of the logic board being abused to carry motor currents.

Answer (score 3):

Probably when turning on the motor it draws enough current that the battery's internal resistance will drop voltage. In turn you see the voltage drop at the battery's terminals.
When a DC motor starts up it needs a relatively large current in order to develop torque.
You could try and connect a capacitor in parallel with the battery. This cap should provide the initial start-up current for the motor. This will not guarante that the motor will run since we do not know the specs. However a quick look at the datasheet suggests: I_motor = P / U -> 1.3W/3V = 434 mA. Is your battery able to provide that current??

So.. Lots of questions about the specs of motor and battery.

edited:
Ok, motor is able to start if connected directly.
So my hint is to decouple the MCU voltage rail from the motor supply rail. I guess the voltage drop affects the MCU and it is not able to drive the FET properly. Maybe a brownout occurs and a subsequent reset.

Decoupling with a diode (possibly lowest forward voltage) and stabilizing with a capacitor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMay64.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

2nd edit:

Since you updated your schematic I've updated mine:

Note: The BAT Pin is the output from the MCP73831, this is a battery charger circuit with programmable charging currents, etc. So this is the wrong place to hook up the motor. Probably by just connecting the motor directly to the battery will lead you to the desired behaviour. If not, just add the diode and a capacitor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwbc9T.png)</sup>

Comment: As I said above, the motor will cycle on if I connect it directly to the battery so I know the battery can power it. The only info on the motor is what the company provided on that page from the link. And sorry I forgot to post the battery info. It's a batt I got from Amazon so I don't really have a datasheet for it. But here's the Amazon link:  https://www.amazon.com/Lithium-Rechargeable-connector-Atomic-Market/dp/B01KJ07A2Q

Comment: But the battery is rated at 2500mAh. As is my understanding that means it should be able to supply around 2.5A for an hour before it dies. So I assume it would be able to handle the 434mA at start up

Comment: I've update my schematic above.  I'm not sure how to implement your suggestion given the battery is actually connected directly to the MCU.  The MCU has a built-in battery charging circuit.  The MCU provides a "BAT" pin which allows you to connect directly to the battery that's connected to the MCU.  I don't think my initial schematic illustrated that fact.  Is there a way to decouple the MCU from the motor supply rail given this setup?

Comment: @anonymous_blackness the Adafruit setup is not engineered to power large external loads such as motors.  For that you'll need a different power solution.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I can connect the motor directly to the BAT pin and GND and it will run just fine.  The issue comes up only when I try to switch it on when it's connected to the FET.  Can you recommend or suggest a different power solution.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Adafruit states the BAT pin is connected directly to "the positive voltage to/from the JST jack for the optional Lipoly battery".  So the motor is being powered directly from the battery is my understanding.

Comment: It's still not a solution intended or rated to run motors.   You may be able to find the most immediate failure, by *as already mentioned* finding the place in the circuit where voltage is being undesirably dropped.  But that will not make it safe to abuse in this way.  If you want to run motors, you need to design the entire circuit carrying their power for that from the start.